# Jquery plugin not merging defaults with options

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have created my own jquery plugin. It is setup like so.

```
;(function ($)
{
    $.fn.bpeditor = function (options)
    {
        return this.each(function() 
        {
            // Merge passed options with defaults
            vars.options = $.extend({}, $.fn.bpeditor.defaults, options);

            alert(vars.options.test);
         }
     }

     var vars =
     {
         options: null
     };

     $.bpeditor.defaults =
     {
         user: 'a',
         dkey: 'b',
         side: 'c',
         test: 'd'
     };

})(jQuery);
```

I call it like so:

```
$('div#canvas').bpeditor
({
    user: 'user1',
    dkey: 'dkey1'
});
```

As you can see, I am passing in the 'user', and 'dkey' options but not 'test'. Test has a default value and it's not being set in the plugin. The alert in the plugin should display the contents of vars.options.test which should be filled with the contents of $.bpeditor.defaults but it's coming back as undefined.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You forgot a `.fn.`

```
$.fn.bpeditor.defaults = {
    ...
};
```

NB: it's unusual to expose your default options so that they can be modified outside of the plugin.

It's more common for them to be a lexically scoped variable that only the plugin can access.  There's also no need to recreate the options variable inside the `.each` loop - all of these affected elements should be sharing the same option state:

```
(function($) {

    // only created once, shared between all instances
    var defaults = {
        ...
    };

    $.fn.bpeditor = function (options) {
        options = $.extend(true, {}, defaults, options);
        return this.each(function() {
            alert(vars.options.test);
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

The `$.extend()` line deep copies the defaults and then the supplied options into a new empty object, re-using the `options` variable - ensuring that the `defaults` object remains constant and that the passed object isn't modified.

Comment: Because there's more problems than just a missing .fn. (syntax error, return before var, etc) But you've updated your answer so I'll take it back. :)

Comment: @Syon you shouldn't downvote for not spotting trivial syntax errors.  Also, what `return before var`?  That return is inside a different function.  Other than a missing `)` on the function (copy and paste error?) and the missing `.fn.` his code actually works.

Comment: I see what you're saying; my assumption with the syntax error was that they meant to use a `)` instead of the `}` (just before `var vars`, in that instance the return and vars are all part of the bpeditor function. I read the errors wrong - never saw the defaults defined outside the function like that. Replace that `}` with a `)` and you can see why I thought the code was all jacked up, lol.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your response. It was just the missing fn in the end. Thank you for the advise about jquery best practices. I have 'got by' by looking at examples on the internet and everyone seems to have a different way of doing things (to a point). I've made a few changes to my code based on your advice and it's all working fine now. I would love to show someone like you the whole plugin so it could be critiqued properly. Would you be willing to do that? It would help massively!

Comment: @Alnitak I also have methods within this plugin. How would I access options within those functions?

Comment: @codemonkey depends on your code structure - the plugin is technically only the `$.fn.xxx` function, not the IIFE wrapper around it.

Answer (score 0):

[FiddleSticks](http://jsfiddle.net/Vjr3c/)

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.bpeditor = function(options) {
        var defaults = {
            user: 'a',
            dkey: 'b',
            side: 'c',
            test: 'd'
        };
        // Merge passed options with defaults
        options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        return this.each(function() {
            // Tooltip plugin code here
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Ya - it's overriding the defaults with the new options. How is that incorrect?

Comment: my mistake - I forget that you're re-initialising the entire object each time the function is called.  Other patterns I've seen more commonly treat the default options as a static object that shouldn't be modified.

Comment: Ahh - np. Although if the user does need to preserve the defaults for some kind of comparison then my version would be incorrect. Guess it depends on what they plan on doing. I usually don't need the defaults if new options were passed through so I simplified the code.